# Why do some favicons disappear after rebooting iPad?

Tags: ipad

I have a number of web pages added to my iPad home screens. After rebooting the iPad , I noticed that many of the favicons disappeared and were replaced by a generic image.  Is this a bug in iOS 8?  Why does this happen, and is there a quick way of restoring the favicons?

Comment: in Safari ? version ?

Comment: The web page icons were added to iPad home screens using whatever version of Safari comes with iOS 8, or, if I added the icon using an earlier release of iOS, then whatever version of Safari was the latest at that time. When I am viewing the icons, I am not using Safari, but just looking at an iPad home screen.